# jQuery animate NaNpx error

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-animate

I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.toggle').toggle(
        function() {
            $(".slide").animate({ "left": "-=190px" }, "slow" );}, 
        function() {
            $(".slide").animate({ "left": "=190px" }, "slow" );})
});
```

and I am getting this error in Firebug:

```
Error in parsing value for 'left'. Declaration dropped.
NaNpx
```

Please explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? That use of toggle was removed.

Comment: Is the code `"left": "=190px" ` a typo or is that what you're trying to use? If so, remove the equals sign or add a plus or minus in front of it.

Comment: @j08691 version jquery-1.10.2. And bingo. The missing plus solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @j08691 you should post as answer so he can accept

Comment: @DaveStein - it's really just a typo.

Comment: Still an answer to be accepted so it's not on the list of unanswered ;)

Comment: @j08691 I agree with Dave ;)

Comment: @DaveStein (and @lunar) - oh alright ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `"left": "=190px"` is a typo. If so, remove the equals sign or add a plus or minus in front of it.